# Is this set open or closed?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $(2, 3]$ open or closed, or both? I don't think it is open because no neighbourhood of the point 3 is totally contained in $(2, 3]$. Since it is not open, it must be closed. If it is closed then, $(-\infty, 2] \cup (3, \infty)$ must be open. But no neighbourhood of 2 is completely in $(-\infty, 2] \cup (3, \infty)$.

Is it that this set is neither open nor closed?

Comment: What is the topology you are working with? The answer depends on it.

Comment: In the standard topology it is neither open nor closed.

Comment: A set is __not__ a door.

Comment: @ThePortakal, actually you can argue that a door can be either closed, or completely open, or somewhere in between. If you define a door to be open only when an average person can pass through, and closed when it looks as if a part of the wall, then there are situations in between, which are neither open nor closed. Same idea can work here in order to "illustrate" the possibilities, as detailed in Hagen's answer.

Comment: By $(-\infty, 2]\cap (3,\infty)$, you actually mean $(-\infty, 2]\cup (3,\infty)$, don't you?  $(-\infty, 2]\cap (3,\infty)$ is empty.

Comment: @Eric_ but can a door be both open *and* closed, like $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think this is the first time I have ever posted a relevant YouTube link to se.math: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/394

Comment: @ThePortakal This is easily one of the best instructional sentences I've seen with regards to topology. I will be using this with future students for sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have some misconception. Open and closed are not opposites of each other. More precisely, we can have sets that are (all as subsets of $\mathbb R$ in standard topology)

- neiter open nor closed: $(0,1]$
- both open and closed: $\mathbb R$
- open and not closed: $(0,1)$
- closed and not open: $[0,1]$

Comment: An arbitrary intersection of open sets is not necessarily open. Is it right to say that it can be closed or neither closed nor open because $(0, 1] = \cup_{n} (0, 1 + 1/n)$?

Comment: @LateLearner You have $\cap$ and $\cup$ confused.  $\cup$ is the sign for set union, because it looks like the letter ‘U’ in ‘union’.

Comment: @MJD: I learned among $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$, the $\cup$ is the one that produces the larger set as a result, because the bowl opening upward collects everything, whereas elements really have to cling to it to stay within the bowl in the $\cap$ orientation.

Answer (score 3):

It's neither open nor closed in standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. You have argued it's not open. It's not closed since you can find a sequence in $A=(2,3]$ converging to $2$, which is not contained in $A$.

"Since it is not open, it must be closed." is not correct in general. Closed is not opposite to open, "not open" is.

But if you are considering subspace topology, it's both open and closed.